# How to parse a graphql response in flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, dart, graphql

I am trying to parse my graphql response from my neo4j-graphql backend in my flutter app. I am using the flutter_graphql plugin to make queries to the back end. However, when I try to parse the response(JSON) I am getting 'LinkHashMap is not a subtype of Users Map.'

I tried modifying my serializing classes that will parse the response but to no available .below is the JSON response from neo4j graphql

```
 /*I HAVE EDITED THE JSON RESPONSE. THE FULL JSON RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER IS AS BELOW*/
{
  "data": {
    "User": [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "city": "NewYork",
        "country": "User",
        "captionType": "User",
        "state": "New York",
        "firstName": "example2",
        "lastname": "example",
        "email": "example2@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "extensions": {
    "type": "READ_ONLY"
  }
}
```

below are the classes that represent the above response

```dart
    @JsonSerializable()
    class User {
      final int userId;
      final String email ;
      final String country ;
      final String firstName;
      final String gender ;
      final String city ;
      final String dateOfBirth ;
      final String state;
      final String captionType;
      final String lastname;
     User({this.userId,this.email,this.country,this.firstName,this.gender,this.dateOfBirth,this.state,this.captionType,this.city,this.lastname});

     factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json)=> _$UserFromJson(json);
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

    }

    class Users{
      final List<User>users;
      Users({this.users});

      factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
        var list = parsedJson['users'] as List;
        List<User> usersList = list.map((i) => User.fromJson(i)).toList();
        return Users(
            users: usersList
        );
      }
    }

    //below is the graphql configuration in my seperate GraphQl.dart file
    class GraphQLConfiguration {
      static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
        uri: "http://localhost:7474/graphql/",
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: ************",
        },
      );
      static final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
        getToken: () async => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
        // OR
        // getToken: () => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
      );


      static ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> initailizeClient() {
        ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
          GraphQLClient(
            cache: InMemoryCache(),
            link: httpLink,
          ),
        );
        return client;
      }

      static GraphQLClient clientToQuery() {
        return GraphQLClient(
          cache: OptimisticCache(
              dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
          link: httpLink,
        );
      }
    }

    //below is my main.dart file where am trying to parse the response


    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
          title: 'Flutter Graphql Client',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            '/': (context) => MyHomePage(), //RootPage(auth: new Auth(),),
          },
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      Widget listViewWidget(List<Users> users) {
        return MediaQuery.removePadding(
          context: context, removeTop: true,
          child:  ListView.builder(
              itemCount: users.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('users:$users'),


                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),

        );
      }

      String readUser = """
      query{
        User(userId:1){
          userId
          city
          country
          captionType
           state
          firstName
           lastname
          email

        }
      }   


      """;


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GraphQLProvider(
         client: GraphQLConfiguration.initailizeClient(),
            child: CacheProvider(
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Flutter Graphql Client'),
                ),
                body:Query(
                  options: QueryOptions(
                      document: readUser),
                  builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
                    if (result.errors!= null) {
                      print('$result.errors');
                     return Text(result.errors.toString());

                    } if (result.errors== null){
                      print(('$result'));
                      print(('${result.data}'));


                    } if (result.loading){
                      return Center(
                          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                            radius: 13.0,
                          ));
                    }

                      return listViewWidget(result.data);
                  },
                )

                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

I am expecting the info to be parsed through the Users class and displayed through the listViewWidget. However I am getting'LinkHashMap is not a subtype of Users Map.'

Answer (score 0):

You can parse any JSON using https://app.quicktype.io/, below is the model class for your JSON

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final responseModel = responseModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ResponseModel responseModelFromJson(String str) => ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseModelToJson(ResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseModel {
Data data;
Extensions extensions;

ResponseModel({
    this.data,
    this.extensions,
});

factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseModel(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    extensions: json["extensions"] == null ? null : Extensions.fromJson(json["extensions"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data == null ? null : data.toJson(),
    "extensions": extensions == null ? null : extensions.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
List<User> user;

Data({
    this.user,
});

factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    user: json["User"] == null ? null : List<User>.from(json["User"].map((x) => User.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "User": user == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(user.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class User {
int userId;
String city;
String country;
String captionType;
String state;
String firstName;
String lastname;
String email;

User({
    this.userId,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.captionType,
    this.state,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastname,
    this.email,
});

factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    userId: json["userId"] == null ? null : json["userId"],
    city: json["city"] == null ? null : json["city"],
    country: json["country"] == null ? null : json["country"],
    captionType: json["captionType"] == null ? null : json["captionType"],
    state: json["state"] == null ? null : json["state"],
    firstName: json["firstName"] == null ? null : json["firstName"],
    lastname: json["lastname"] == null ? null : json["lastname"],
    email: json["email"] == null ? null : json["email"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "userId": userId == null ? null : userId,
    "city": city == null ? null : city,
    "country": country == null ? null : country,
    "captionType": captionType == null ? null : captionType,
    "state": state == null ? null : state,
    "firstName": firstName == null ? null : firstName,
    "lastname": lastname == null ? null : lastname,
    "email": email == null ? null : email,
    };
}

class Extensions {
String type;

Extensions({
    this.type,
});

factory Extensions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Extensions(
    type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "type": type == null ? null : type,
    };
}
```

use this code to parse your response

```
ResponseModel  responseModel = responseModelFromJson(result.data);
return listViewWidget(responseModel.data.user);
```

Comment: your code seems robust but how do I implement it in the listViewWidget(). That's the key place I am missing it. Could you also show how I can use your code in the main.dart file?

Comment: I am still wrapping my head around state management in flutter but I believe your code works but I just don't really know how to call it my listViewWidget().

Comment: sorry I am thinking the classes to parse the query are wrong because I posted the incomplete json response.. I have edited the full response from graphiQL in my question I did not post the full response. I have tried using your recent edit but it has still failed. Is it possible to try it again with my edits? As in if it's not much trouble please review your solution with respect to the latest json response and the classes to parse the latest json edit that I have included. Many Thanks

Comment: hey bro tried I am getting this .     "flutter:_StreamBuilderBaseState<QueryResult,AsyncSnapshot<QueryResult>>#d2866):
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
"

Comment: please replace responseModelFromJson(result.data) to ResponseModel.fromJson(result.data) and check